# Method Not Firing on GridView Page Change

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a method that assigns the text of button that resides inside of an item template in a gridview. The method fires fine in Page_PreRender or Page_Load but as soon as someone changes the page via the built in paging links the resulting page does not assign the text to the button. I called the method in both the PageIndexChanged and PageIndexChanging events and still I get blank buttons. Is there an event I can put this in that will cause it to run when the gridview pageindex is changed?

```cs
    protected void populateActivationText()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in allItemGrid.Rows)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button activationButtonAll = row.FindControl("activationButtonAll") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button;
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox activeCheckAll = row.Cells[7].Controls[0] as System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox;
            if (activeCheckAll.Checked)
            {
                activationButtonAll.Text = "Deactivate";
            }
            else
            {
                activationButtonAll.Text = "Activate";
            }
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in searchGrid.Rows)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button activationButtonSearch = row.FindControl("activationButtonSearch") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button;
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox activeCheckSearch = row.Cells[7].Controls[0] as System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox;
            if (activeCheckSearch.Checked)
            {
                activationButtonSearch.Text = "Deactivate";
            }
            else
            {
                activationButtonSearch.Text = "Activate";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `PageIndexChanged` and `PageIndexChanging`?

Comment: protected void allItemGrid_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            populateActivationText();
        }

Comment: Let's see how your Page_PreRender and Page_Load look like. Take note that Page_PreRender fires after PageIndexChanged and PageIndexChanging. Let's see your Page_PreRender code

Comment: EVENT (arguments){populateActivatonText();} --- I got this working by calling populateActivationText() in the gridview's DataBound event, I don't know if that's the right way to do it but it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by calling populateActivationText in the gridview's DataBound event. I don't think that's the best way to do it but its working as expected now.

```
protected void allItemGrid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            populateActivationText();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Set the `PageIndex` for the new page and do the `DataBind` and try calling your method that sets the button text..

```
 protected void allItemGrid_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
      allItemGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
      allItemGrid.DataBind();
      populateActivationText();
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working, I had tried to rebind the gridview in previous attempts without any results. NewPageIndex is a property of the PageIndexChanging event. Thank for helping, if I don't get any advice on how to do this in C# I suppose I can write it in .js, just seems like this shouldn't really be a mystery.